# I am using Tor on personal computer used for work, when attempting to open TOR I received the following message

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

```
4/20/2017 3:10:51 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/20/2017 3:10:51 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/20/2017 3:10:51 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/20/2017 3:10:51 AM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/20/2017 3:10:51 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
4/20/2017 3:10:51 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
4/20/2017 3:12:01 AM.700 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at 154.35.175.225:443) 
4/20/2017 3:12:01 AM.700 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
4/20/2017 3:12:01 AM.700 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
```

I use this computer for work, I assume this means boss has control of what I am doing...?  Downloaded TOR several weeks ago and when employer had Server company remote in, my TOR was removed from desktop and internet explorer was added in its place... New to TOR, just want to know what this message was and how I can tell if he is seeing my traffic, etc